# Marketing Cloud Multi-org - basics

Tags: marketing-cloud, sales-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, multi-org

I'm going to install multi-org functionality for my MC account. At first I should install a connector itself (version 5.494 or higher) and then log a support ticket in the Salesforce Help and Training portal to complete the upgrade. The question is - what about API user and Salesforce System user? Should I proceed with standard configuration for non-multi-org first? Or are they a completely different process'?

Answer (score 0):

The api user is required for the connector to work. It is what allows the connector to access records. If you have not already done so, I highly recommend getting Premiere Plus support at least through the setup phase.

Comment: So anyway I should at first go through a process of configuration both Sales Cloud and Marketing Cloud orgs and after that enable multi-org functionality?

Comment: Talk to your account rep.  We didn't go in this order, but with enablement of multi-org.  I would also recommend premier support...You'd think that being part of the SF umbrella that these systems would work together well.  Not true.

Answer (score 0):

The [order in the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_upgrade_to_multi-org.htm&type=5) is a bit confusing, it says before upgrading to multi-org, review that you have Enterprise 2.0 Marketing Cloud account with multi-org is enabled.

The documentation also assumes you have a connection with Sales Cloud already established.